# nifi unit testing: RecordReader fetching empty records

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to write a unit test for a cusom nifi processor:

```
runner.setProperty(.....); // runner is instance of TestRunner
runner.setProperty(....);
RecordSchema inputRecordSchema = inputRecordSchema(); // create schema based on fields in input record
final Object[] recordArray = recordArray(inputRecordSchema); // create some test records(type MapRecord)
parser.addRecord((Object) recordArray); // parser is an instance of MockRecordParser
...
runner.run();
```

In my implementation of onTrigger method:

```
try (final InputStream in = session.read(inpuFlowFile);
             final RecordReader reader = readerFactory.createRecordReader(inpuFlowFile, in, getLogger())) {

     ....
     ....
     Record record;
     ....
     ....
     while((record = reader.nextRecord()) != null) {
         //process record
     }
     ....
     ....
}
```

I expect reader.nextRecord() to fetch me the test records of type MapRecord, with data populated in unit test. But what I see is empty MapRecord instances.

What am I missing in my unit test